# saned: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied

Tags: usb, permissions, scanner, sane

I tried to setup a network scanner with SANE following this tutorial: [Sane Daemon Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial)

But if I try to add the scanner on a client, it doesn't work as saned seams to have no access to the USB-port.

```
Feb  9 18:55:47 druckserver systemd[1]: Started Scanner Service  (10.1.20.25:50515).
Feb  9 18:55:47 druckserver saned[2005]: saned (AF-indep+IPv6+systemd) from sane-backends 1.0.27 starting up
Feb  9 18:55:47 druckserver saned[2005]: check_host: access by remote host: ::ffff:10.1.20.25
Feb  9 18:55:47 druckserver systemd-resolved[1172]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.1.10.1.
Feb  9 18:55:52 druckserver saned[2005]: init: access granted to User@::ffff:10.1.20.25
Feb  9 18:55:57 druckserver saned[2005]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
Feb  9 18:55:57 druckserver saned[2005]: message repeated 3 times: [ io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied]
Feb  9 18:55:57 druckserver saned[2005]: saned exiting
Feb  9 18:56:35 druckserver systemd[1]: Started Scanner Service (10.1.20.25:50531).
Feb  9 18:56:35 druckserver saned[2013]: saned (AF-indep+IPv6+systemd) from sane-backends 1.0.27 starting up
Feb  9 18:56:35 druckserver saned[2013]: check_host: access by remote host: ::ffff:10.1.20.25
Feb  9 18:56:35 druckserver saned[2013]: init: access granted to User@::ffff:10.1.20.25
Feb  9 18:56:41 druckserver saned[2013]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
Feb  9 18:56:41 druckserver saned[2013]: message repeated 3 times: [ io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied]
Feb  9 18:56:41 druckserver saned[2013]: saned exiting
```

What pops from this syslog is this line:

```
Feb  9 18:56:41 druckserver saned[2013]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
```

I have absoltuly no idea on how to fix that. Do I need to add the user "sane" to a specific group?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it solved by adding:

```
RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

to */etc/systemd/system/saned.socket*
and by adding the sane-user to the lp group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp saned
```

Comment: Did you already have a saned.socket file, because I tried to open that file and there was nothing there?

Comment: Yes, I had. Maybe your installation is broken, or sane is not running?

Comment: I face the same problem as @guttermonk and, as you mention, sane is not running. The question remains, why the warnning is issued and how to solve it?

Comment: I had to first create /etc/systemd/system/saned.socket which was missing, but then this suggested fix worked to eliminate the journalctl error message I was getting.  !thanks