# colord-sane: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied

Tags: boot, permissions, scanner, sane

I get the following errors all in a row in my journalctl after booting:

```
colord-sane[4901]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
colord-sane[4901]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
colord-sane[4901]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
colord-sane[4901]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
colord-sane[4901]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
```

I don't know if it's related to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209481/saned-io-hpmud-musb-c-2101-invalid-usb-open-permission-denied), but the permission denied issue looks very similar. I tried going through those steps looking for parallels between saned and colord-sane but wasn't sure what user to add to which file, or what group it needed to be added to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened `lib/systemd/system/colord.service` and noticed it had `User=colord`.

So I tried adding the colord user to the lp group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp colord
```

And, after a reboot, the error is gone! I hope this helps if you have a similar error.