# Webcam failing : mtp-ptobe and colord-sane issue

Tags: webcam, udev, video-recording

Not sure whats going on here. This is ubuntu 22.04. Suddenly after a reboot (which installed patches) the video devices fail, most notably the logitech webcam. What I see for it in syslog is

```
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac kernel: [22230.498881] usb 3-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac kernel: [22230.498883] usb 3-6.2: Product: HD Pro Webcam C920
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac kernel: [22230.498885] usb 3-6.2: SerialNumber: 547C7AAF
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6.2"
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 16 was not an MTP device
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6.2"
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 16 was not an MTP device
Apr 23 20:45:02 orac colord-sane: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
```

I think it must be the mtp-probe, maybe something about udev rules, but I also wonder about the colord-sane.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245202/colord-sane-io-hpmud-musb-c-2101-invalid-usb-open-permission-denied

Comment: turns out the mtp-probe is normal, the colord message went away on a reboot, but still the permission faillure. Ultimately I gave up and upgraded to 23.04 which I was going to do soon anyway. Now its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment:
It turns out the mtp-probe is normal, the colord message went away on a reboot, but still the permission failure. Ultimately I gave up and upgraded to 23.04 which I was going to do soon anyway. Now its working properly.